# Unpivot odd no of columns in Pyspark dataframe in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have 69 cols which are to be unpivoted, I tried this kind of code :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
group = Inv_df.groupBy('Project', 'Project Description')

# Use pairs of column name and value in the stack function

unpivotExpr = "stack(69, '2015-04-01', 2015-04-01, '2015-05-01', 2015-05-01, '2015-06-01', 2015-06-01, '2015-07-01', 2015-07-01, '2015-08-01', 2015-08-01, '2015-09-01', 2015-09-01, '2015-10-01', 2015-10-01, '2015-11-01', 2015-11-01, '2015-12-01', 2015-12-01, '2016-01-01', 2016-01-01, '2016-02-01', 2016-02-01, '2016-03-01', 2016-03-01, '2016-04-01', 2016-04-01, '2016-05-01', 2016-05-01, '2016-06-01', 2016-06-01, '2016-07-01', 2016-07-01, '2016-08-01', 2016-08-01, '2016-09-01', 2016-09-01, '2016-10-01', 2016-10-01, '2016-11-01', 2016-11-01, '2016-12-01', 2016-12-01, '2017-01-01', 2017-01-01, '2017-02-01', 2017-02-01, '2017-03-01', 2017-03-01, '2017-04-01', 2017-04-01, '2017-05-01', 2017-05-01, '2017-06-01', 2017-06-01, '2017-07-01', 2017-07-01, '2017-08-01', 2017-08-01, '2017-09-01', 2017-09-01, '2017-10-01', 2017-10-01, '2017-11-01', 2017-11-01, '2017-12-01', 2017-12-01, '2018-01-01', 2018-01-01, '2018-02-01', 2018-02-01, '2018-03-01', 2018-03-01, '2018-04-01', 2018-04-01, '2018-05-01', 2018-05-01, '2018-06-01', 2018-06-01, '2018-07-01', 2018-07-01, '2018-08-01', 2018-08-01, '2018-09-01', 2018-09-01, '2018-10-01', 2018-10-01, '2018-11-01', 2018-11-01, '2018-12-01', 2018-12-01, '2019-01-01', 2019-01-01, '2019-02-01', 2019-02-01, '2019-03-01', 2019-03-01, '2019-04-01', 2019-04-01, '2019-05-01', 2019-05-01, '2019-06-01', 2019-06-01, '2019-07-01', 2019-07-01, '2019-08-01', 2019-08-01, '2019-09-01', 2019-09-01, '2019-10-01', 2019-10-01, '2019-11-01', 2019-11-01, '2019-12-01', 2019-12-01, '2020-01-01', 2020-01-01, '2020-02-01', 2020-02-01, '2020-03-01', 2020-03-01, '2020-04-01', 2020-04-01, '2020-05-01', 2020-05-01, '2020-06-01', 2020-06-01, '2020-07-01', 2020-07-01, '2020-08-01', 2020-08-01, '2020-09-01', 2020-09-01, '2020-10-01', 2020-10-01, '2020-11-01', 2020-11-01, '2020-12-01', 2020-12-01 ) as (Name, value)"

unPivotDF = group.agg(expr(unpivotExpr))
```

It gave me wrong results, is this method is only for even no of cols.

Please suggest me the right way to unpivot.

Comment: That's not how you use `stack`.  Try `unpivotDF = group.select(expr(unpivotExpr))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unpivot` function as below.

```
display(df.unpivot(["Project", "Project Description"],["2015-04-01", "2015-05-01", "2015-06-01"],"Name", "value"))
```

[image]

Or
else you need to specify proper column name because,
the expression you used takes literal value.

```
   stack(69,'2015-04-01', 2015-04-01,....)
```

In this expression it takes value as `((2015-04)-01)` gives you 2010.

[image]

So, change your column names in such a way that doesn't evaluate in `expr` function.
I changed column names from `2015-04-01` to `2015_04_01`.

And got successful output.

```
unpivotExpr = "stack(3, '2015_04_01',any_value(2015_04_01), '2015_05_01',any_value(2015_05_01),'2015_06_01',any_value(2015_06_01)) as (Name,value)"
display(df.groupBy('Project', 'Project Description').agg(expr(unpivotExpr)))
```

[image]

Or without group by.

```
unpivotExpr = "stack(3, '2015_04_01',2015_04_01, '2015_05_01',2015_05_01,'2015_06_01',2015_06_01) as (Name,value)"
display(df.select("Project", "Project Description",expr(unpivotExpr)))
```

[image]

If you can't able to rename all 69 columns use first approach.